# Select one of two objects, without `IFoo foo = new Foo1();`

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

In order to learn more about this, I wanna ask for the best path

**What I have**

1. I'm consuming 2 web services, one for a version 1 and the other for a version 2
2. In code I use each version by a integer in the client table, `client.ws_version = 1 or 2`

.

```
IWebServiceRepository repository;

if(client.ws_version == 1)
    repository = new WebServiceRepositoryVersion1();
else
    repository = new WebServiceRepositoryVersion2();
```

**What I have learn**

That this is the worst thing to do :)

So the question is **What's the best way to accomplish this?** Facade? Dependency Injection? other process?

Comment: have you considered using WCF? It provides handling for multiple service versions running simultaneously http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731060.aspx

Comment: I'm consuming a WCF Service, `WebServiceRepositoryVersion1` and `WebServiceRepositoryVersion2` are 2 version of a WCF that, in reality, one is an ASMX Service and other is a WCF Service, where based on the `ws_version` I know what to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the statement is that simple its not actually a bad way to go, but you should encapsulate your statement in a `WebServiceRepositoryProvider`

### Code:

```
public class WebServiceRepositoryProvider
{
    public  IWebServiceRepository GetRepository(ClientTable context)
    {
        return context.ws_version == 1 
            ? new WebServiceRepositoryVersion1() 
            : new WebServiceRepositoryVersion2();
    }
}
```

You can configure this functionality with many inversion of control containers, but it would be overkill to implement DI in your app for such a simple function.

Comment: Soon I saw this ScreenCast http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/UnityDependencyInjectionIoCScreencast.aspx my brain cells start to hit each other and I couldn't get what to do, thanks for the heads up.